# Does Damian Wayne ever see his mother again after 'Son of Batman'?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

Bruce takes Damian under his wing in 'Son of Batman', and becomes Robin. However, I wanted to know if Damian ever gets to see his mother again? Even in the comics, was there and evidence that Damian sees Tahlia again?

Comment: Films and comics aren't the same continuity, but yeah. Most recent example I can think of is _Super Sons_. Now to get to a computer and flesh out an answer... :)

Comment: Bruce becomes Robin? Twist!

Answer (score 6):

As Jenayah commented, "Super Sons" #13 and #14 feature Tahlia.[image: The image depicts Robin swinging up to a building, with the right leg lifted, hitting a woman with his kick into the face. Because of the kick, the woman can be seen flinching as she drops her sniper rifle and lets out an: "unff--". Robin tells her: "Hello, mother!", which reveals that Robin is Damian Wayne, and the woman is his mother Talia al Ghul.]

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the animated movie [Son of Batman (2014)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3139072/), then yes. This movie had a sequel called [Batman: Bad Blood (2016)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4870838/), where Damian does meet his mother again, at least once.

During the movie, spoiler below:

> Nightwing was fighting against a mind-controlled Batman (by Talia). At some point, as Nightwing was about to get killed, Damian came to confront his mother: "That's what it's all about in the end, isn't it, Mother? Not the vision of a better world my grandfather had. It's just about control.", after which Talia told Batman to "Start with the bastard. We can always make more." (i.e. kill Damian, we can always make new children).

You will find a video of that scene below: